# La notation du choix dans les prototypes ou variantes d'une même phrase etc. ?

Tags: discussion

*Réflexion*

- Quelle est la notation la plus courante pour représenter des choix
  dans un prototype de phrase ?

  - Les choix sont-ils normalement entre parenthèses ou crochets ?
- Ces notations sont-elles utiles ou décourage-t-on leur emploi au même
  titre que les abréviations ?
- Un moteur de recherche est-il capable de décliner des multiples
  phrases avec ces notations ?
- Pense-t-on que la barre verticale « | » est devenue usuelle pour
  indiquer un choix (OU) entre des éléments ?
- Quelles sont les pratiques recommandées dans l'emploi de cette
  notation avec du contenu de type encyclopédique ?
- Comment représente-t-on dans une seule
  phrase deux choix s'excluant l'un et l'autre et occupant des
  positions distinctes dans la phrase (ex. adverbe antéposé, postposé)
   ?

---

Je pense que normalement je me contente de parenthèses avec des choix séparés par des barres obliques « / ». Je ne m'intéresse pas aux symboles qui représentent des verbes pour l'égalité ou la transformation (*donne, est égal/équivalent à, devient* etc.) que je trouve imprécis. Je m'intéresse plutôt au contexte du prototype de phrase où on répète en changeant un mot, on trouve ça dans des exemples de réponse ou dans des questions. Dans une réponse j'ai été incapable de représenter un choix arbitraire entre deux mots occupant deux positions distinctes dans une même phrase:

> *Es-tu libre/disponible (prochainement) pour qu'on se rencontre
> (bientôt) ?*

---

J'aimerais avoir des opinions sur l'utilité (ou l'inutilité) de la notation dans des contenus du site principal pour représenter des choix ou des variantes de phrases...

Comment: La question n'est pas reliée à l'emploi du tau comme _variable métasyntaxique_. Elle ne porte pas sur la manière de représenter une hésitation avec la finale d'un mot (un sujet bien intéressant par ailleurs) mais plutôt sur des choix entre des mots différents voire se trouvant dans des positions différentes de la phrase.